# How does Node.js as a single threaded runtime, utilize other cores of a CPU?

Tags: node.js

I want to know how Node.js as a single threaded JavaScript runtime/server handles other cores (if any) in a CPU. Should I write any extra code or setup for that? Or it will  automatically utilize all the other cores when get much workload?

I want some details knowledge about this. Also, want some topics and references for study regarding this.

Comment: Have a look at node js workers https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html, there are many guides out there, this seems like it has some meat on it: https://blog.logrocket.com/a-complete-guide-to-threads-in-node-js-4fa3898fe74f/

Comment: Also, I want to know the theory behind in plain but not with code only.

Comment: Good answer is here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/63225073/5992036